# Unable to DELETE DATA in Jena Fuseki while INSERT DATA works perfectly

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki, turtle-rdf

I am trying to delete rules written in turtle in Apache Jena Fuseki with the Jena API, the problem I am facing right now is that a INSERT DATA request works great as you can see :

```
INSERT DATA {
[ rdf:type           swrl:Imp ;
rdfs:comment         "" ;
rdfs:label           "NewRule" ;
swrla:isRuleEnabled  true ;
swrl:body            [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                      rdf:first  []  ;
                      rdf:rest   [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                                   rdf:first  [ rdf:type             swrl:ClassAtom ;
                                                swrl:argument1       :c ;
                                                swrl:classPredicate  :Person
                                              ] ;
                                   rdf:rest   [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                                                rdf:first  [ rdf:type                swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom ;
                                                             swrl:argument1          :d ;
                                                             swrl:argument2          :c ;
                                                             swrl:propertyPredicate  :isAbove
                                                           ] ;
                                                rdf:rest   ()
                                              ]
                                 ]
                    ] ;
swrl:head            [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                      rdf:first  [ rdf:type             swrl:ClassAtom ;
                                   swrl:argument1       :d ;
                                   swrl:classPredicate  :ActionAssemble
                                 ] ;
                      rdf:rest   ()
                    ]
] .
}
```

but the DELETE DATA request which is the exact same syntax give me this error :

```
Line 12, column 9: Blank nodes not allowed in DELETE templates
```

And here is the request :

```
DELETE DATA {
  [ rdf:type           swrl:Imp ;
  rdfs:comment         "" ;
  rdfs:label           "NewRule" ;
  swrla:isRuleEnabled  true ;
  swrl:body            [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                         rdf:first  []  ;
                         rdf:rest   [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                                      rdf:first  [ rdf:type             swrl:ClassAtom ;
                                                   swrl:argument1       :c ;
                                                   swrl:classPredicate  :Person
                                                 ] ;
                                      rdf:rest   [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                                                   rdf:first  [ rdf:type                swrl:IndividualPropertyAtom ;
                                                                swrl:argument1          :d ;
                                                                swrl:argument2          :c ;
                                                                swrl:propertyPredicate  :isAbove
                                                              ] ;
                                                   rdf:rest   ()
                                                 ]
                                    ]
                       ] ;
  swrl:head            [ rdf:type   swrl:AtomList ;
                         rdf:first  [ rdf:type             swrl:ClassAtom ;
                                      swrl:argument1       :d ;
                                      swrl:classPredicate  :ActionAssemble
                                    ] ;
                         rdf:rest   ()
                       ]
] .
}
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: the problem with `DELETE DATA` is that it cannot know which bnode to chose - you know there is only one, but SPARQL cannot know this. There might be multiple in your dataset. You have to put it into a `WHERE`clause and introduce variables for each bnode

Comment: Thank you for your reply, do you know how to properly delete the entire rule with a DELETE WHERE clauses ? @UninformedUser